# React: Animate ternary output components

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I'm surprised by the issue im having with this simple animation procedure. I have a ternary that displays one series of components or another based on a condition. My first thought was to wrap them in a div that animates them once they appear. Unfortunately, its only animating the first condition on page load, switching tabs has no effect. Any thoughts?

```
const dashboard = () => {
  const [pane, setPane] = useState(0);
  const props = useSpring({ opacity: 1, from: { opacity: 0 } });
return (
...
        <MainContent>
          {pane === 0 ? (
            <animated.div style={props}>
              <LastModuleWidget {...mockLastModule} />
              <BookmarkedModules />
              <LatestActivity />
            </animated.div>
          ) : (
            <animated.div style={props}>
              <StatsModule />
              <PreviouslyCompleted />
            </animated.div>
          )}
        </MainContent>
...
)};
```

- Moving the animation wrapper immediately outside of the ternary had no effect.
- I've tried it with Springs (above) and my own implementation, no effect.

Comment: I am using Next.JS if that makes any difference at all. Though, i think this is just a react issue.

Comment: I guess that you need to use `set` inside `useEffect` with `[pane]` as dependencies. https://www.react-spring.io/docs/hooks/use-spring

Comment: @UjinT34 following that, the console log i placed inside my use effect triggers but it doesnt reset the animation

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the core issue is that my `MainContent` container did not have a key prop.

```
  <MainContent key={pane}>
          {pane === 0 ? (
            <_AnimateFadeIn>
              <LastModuleWidget {...mockLastModule} />
              <BookmarkedModules />
              <LatestActivity />
            </_AnimateFadeIn>
          ) : (
            <_AnimateFadeIn>
              <BookmarkedModules />
              <LatestActivity />
            </_AnimateFadeIn>
          )}
  </MainContent>
```

also, for simplicity i reverted back to using my own animation since its a simple fade in:

```
const _AnimateFadeIn = styled.div`
  @keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  animation: fadeIn 0.7s;
`;
```

I'm using styled-components. If you want to recreate this in CSS just write something like:

`div className="_animateFadeIn"` or whatever. Same thing.